# Javascript input masking plugins that work with Meteor Autoform + SimpleSchema?

Tags: meteor

Has anyone here gotten a jQuery masking library to work with Autoform? I'm trying BootStrap Form Helpers

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{> afFieldLabel name="customerInfo.agentPhone"}}
        <input name="customerInfo.agentPhone" type="text" class="form-control track-order-change bfh-phone" required data-schema-key="customerInfo.agentPhone" data-format="ddd ddd-dddd">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have customerInfo.agentPhone set to required in my schema.

When I do this code I lose the ability to validate the form against the schema. The input field can be blank and the error message that says this field can't be blank never shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that I was using `afFieldInput` incorrectly - every time you use `afFieldInput` you have to have an `#if` statement to change the CSS of the wrapping div to show the validation message.

```
    <div class="col-md-12 {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name="customerInfo.agentPhone"}}has-error{{/if}}">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{> afFieldLabel name="customerInfo.agentPhone"}}
        {{> afFieldInput name="customerInfo.agentPhone" class="form-control track-order-change bfh-phone" data-format=" (ddd) ddd-dddd"}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note two things:

1. You have to put `bfh-phone` for the class.
2. You have to put a space in front of the parenthesis " (ddd) ddd-dddd". If you don't and just do "(ddd) ddd-dddd" the `(` gets inserted into the text field on load. And obviously if you're checking to make sure that the text field is not blank, it won't fire because the ( is loaded in there already.

Comment: By chance do you have a full example to share?  I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm struggling as I'm not an expert of Meteor/Autoform.

Comment: There's a much simpler method, just pass in a class to the afFieldInput and use one of the many JQuery mask libs.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used autoform, but looking over the documentation I'm wondering have you tried this:

```
{{> afFieldInput name="customerInfo.agentPhone" data-format="ddd ddd-dddd" }}
```

(obviously adding any additional attributes you may have set to `afFieldInput` before)